# Iterating through comparison of dates in Python Pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime, apply

Right now I am iterating over a pandas dataframe to patch data inconsistencies with datetime columns, but the runtime is brutal.

```
def fix(row):
        return row.datetime_column2 if row.datetime_column1 > row.datetime_column2 else row.datetime_column1

df['datetime_column1'] = df.apply(fix, axis = 1)
```

Is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: Could you combine the two datetime columns, remove duplicates, and then sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can use this vectorized approach:

```
df['datetime_column1'] =  \
    np.where(df['datetime_column1'] > df['datetime_column2'], 
             df['datetime_column2'],
             df['datetime_column1'])
```

or:

```
df['datetime_column1'] = df[['datetime_column1','datetime_column2']].min(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible with pandas/numpy, don't use for loops as you do with (axis=1).  Try the following. Should work for dates too.

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data={'column_1':[1,3,5,5],'column_2':[0,4,1,6] })
df.loc[df.column_1>df.column_2, 'column_1'] = df.column_2
```

Comment: Use `.loc` instead as `.ix` is getting deprecated